Is there an AGPL 3.0 ONLY license?
The AGPL 3.0 license is actually the AGPL 3.0 or later license due to the 14. Revised Versions of this License. paragraph:
  14. Revised Versions of this License.

  The Free Software Foundation may publish revised and/or new versions of
the GNU Affero General Public License from time to time.  Such new versions
will be similar in spirit to the present version, but may differ in detail to
address new problems or concerns.

  Each version is given a distinguishing version number.  If the
Program specifies that a certain numbered version of the GNU Affero General
Public License "or any later version" applies to it, you have the
option of following the terms and conditions either of that numbered
version or of any later version published by the Free Software
Foundation.  If the Program does not specify a version number of the
GNU Affero General Public License, you may choose any version ever published
by the Free Software Foundation.

  If the Program specifies that a proxy can decide which future
versions of the GNU Affero General Public License can be used, that proxy's
public statement of acceptance of a version permanently authorizes you
to choose that version for the Program.

  Later license versions may give you additional or different
permissions.  However, no additional obligations are imposed on any
author or copyright holder as a result of your choosing to follow a
later version.

Is there a AGPL 3.0 only license or how can I modify the current license to create such a license?

I think you may be over-reading s14.  The substantive paragraph says that

Each version is given a distinguishing version number.  If the
Program specifies that a certain numbered version of the GNU Affero General
Public License "or any later version" applies to it, you have the
option of following the terms and conditions either of that numbered
version or of any later version published by the Free Software
Foundation.

Note the bolded text.  Unless you have explicitly released your code under "AGPLv3 or any later version", there's no reason to think that clause applies, because its application is conditional on the option "or any later version" being applied by you.  Later in that same paragraph the licence says how it may be applied if someone releases code "under AGPL" without specifying a version, but you can easily avoid that, also.
So to do what you want to do, just release "under AGPLv3".

Technically listing the v3 without an "or any later version" is sufficient but I would suggest explicitly specifying "v3-only".
